# How to use RadEditor in dnn module?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, radeditor

I want to use RadEditor in my dnn module. We usually add reference of control to project then add register tag to page and at the final we can write code and use this control.Now Which reference should be added  and How to fill radeditor with a string and read a string that exist into editor?
Please advice.

Comment: Are you talking about DNN TextEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNN Texteditor is the control that you want.  In most DNN 6 and 7 editions, the default editor is a wrapper around Telerik's RadEditor.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="TextEditor" Src="~/controls/texteditor.ascx" %>
```

...

```
<dnn:TextEditor ID="txtHtmlEditor" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px" ChooseMode="true" HtmlEncode="false"></dnn:TextEditor>
```

In your .ascx.cs code, you have the following reference:

```
protected DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.TextEditor txtHtmlEditor;
```

...

You can just set or get the .Text property to initialize or get the content.

```
txtHtmlEditor.Text = "<p>Html Content</p>";
```